# Problema de consulta - Acentuação

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, algoritmo-de-busca

Meu banco MySQL está em UTF-8, páginas em UTF-8, até aí tudo funcionando. Nenhum problema com *charset*.

O problema se dá quando pesquiso algo (empresa) na busca, por exemplo:

Eu digito "A" e ele retorna as empresas que possuem essa letra inicial **+** as empresas que iniciam com "Ó", pois no banco ele transforma o "Ó" em "Ã“". No exemplo citado ele puxa as "Óticas" que tem cadastrado.

Sinceramente nao sei como resolver. Tentei mudar os parâmetros na busca, mas sem sucesso.

Talvez se forçar algo como *case-sensitive* para acentos (se é que é possível).

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como resolver isso? De preferência sem alterar o BD.

OBS: Programação em PHP.

Answer (score 1):

1ª Alternativa:

Abra o arquivo `.php` no notepad++ e vá no botão menu `formatar` e selecione a opção: `Codificação em UTF-8 (sem BOM)`, é possivel que o arquivo fonte do PHP não esteja `utf-8`.

2ª Alternativa:

A página `.html` que está renderizando não esta no padrão utf-8, então adicione esta linha a ela:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

3ª Alternativa:

Adicione isto no inicio do seu arquivo `.php`

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

4ª Alternativa:

Adicione a seguinte linha ao arquivo `.htaccess`

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

5ª Alternativa:

Edite a seguinte linha no arquivo `php.ini` para ficar como abaixo:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

6ª Alternativa:

Caso não tenha acesso ao arquivo `php.ini` adicione a seguitne linha no topo do documento `.php`:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

7ª Alternativa:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Ricardo, todas possibilidades testadas, mas sem sucesso. Sem alteração.

Comment: @MarcoGarcia verei outras alternativas

Comment: Veja qual a collate do seu banco

Comment: Use os seguintes comando e ponha os resultados aqui: 
use banco_de_dados;
show variables like "character_set_database";
show variables like "collation_database";

Comment: character_set_database > utf8

Comment: Exemplo da minha consulta: (e.nomefantasia LIKE 'A%') ... e no final ele retorna "Ã“TICA CAROL", por exemplo. Já tentei inserir COLLATION direto, na linha, mas não deu em nada.

Comment: Quando você faz a pesquisa pelo console do mysql da este problema?

Comment: Isso, exatamente. Tanto pelo console quanto pelo PHP tenho o mesmo problema

Comment: O problema então deve estar no banco

Comment: Alguma sugestão?

Comment: @MarcoGarcia estou pensando

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer esses alterações e verificar se as mesmas irão funcionar.

1. Adicionar no inicio da pagina PHP header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
2. Colocar após a conexão com o MySql o comando $mysqli->query('SET NAMES utf8');
3. Usar o meta Tag < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
4. Tentar trocar o idioma do site para uma outra linguagem < meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="pt-br" />

Veja se funciona.

Comment: Roberto, testado, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Se ele está transformando sua entrada na query do banco, então há um problema no charset sim. Uma maneira de forçar sua entrada de dado para a sua query é usando: html_entity_decode($data), ou fazer melhor, abra ele no bloco de notas e salve como ASCII, depois na sua IDE converta ele para UTF-8.

Comment: Ivan, testado, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Marco, você consegue enviar os arquivos onde estão ocorrendo o problema pra gente te ajudar.

Comment: Mando sim, Ivan. Como manda aqui no SO? Agora que comecei utilizar...

Comment: faz um zip e me manda o link, tipo: https://www.wetransfer.com/, dropbox, etc...